# Play Framework 2 render error, util list

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

This is my code:

```
public static Result continents()
{
  List<Continent> cont = Continent.find.all();
  return ok(views.html.index.render(cont));
}
```

I get the error: `"render can not be applied in this (java util.list. <models)"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Does your index template accept a parameter? Show us the first few lines of your `index.scala.html`.

Comment: Now is already ok, I added the lines in index.scala: @(cont: List[Continent]) and there is no error. 

I'm a beginner Tell me, how to display the list  in index.scala.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `views.html.`. Some IDEs try to complete this path or show errors. I have to same problem shown by my IDE IntelliJ IDEA 13 but it complies without errors.